# How do I introduce a second equation to solve a first equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following equation

$$\tag{1} M =\frac{n_{1}\cos \theta_1 - n_{2}\cos \theta_2 }{n_{1}\cos \theta_1 + n_{2}\cos \theta_2} \times \frac{n_{1}\cos \theta_1 - n_{3}\cos \theta_3 }{n_{1}\cos \theta_1 + n_{3}\cos \theta_3} $$

and I know that Snell's law means that:

$$\tag{2} n_{1}\sin \theta_1 = n_{2}\sin \theta_2 = n_{3}\sin \theta_3$$

I am trying to solve this equation for $n_{1}$, **but how do I put both these equations as inputs to simplify eq 1?**

This is my first time using *Mathematica* and I tried to solve (1) by doing

```
Solve[ ...... == M , n_{1}]
```

**But I don't know how to introduce eq. 2 into this system.**

---

*Update*

I introduced equation (2) into the command according to what was suggested below in the following [link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingEquationsAndInequalities.html).

```
Solve[ {...... == M , n_{1}*sin(\theta_1)==n_{2}*sin(\theta_2)==n_{3}*sin(\theta_3)}, n_{1}]
```

**But can I do that? Can I add two equalities into a single equation of 3 parts as shown in equation (2)?**

Comment: For basics see [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingEquationsAndInequalities.html). In particular, `=` is an assignment.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include Mathematica code that you have tried so far.

Comment: @Syed , I am yet to try any code that isn't the one I wrote above.

Comment: You didn't define `nsam` so far!

Comment: My bad, it should have been $n_1$. I hope this makes more sense. I will update on things I have done, but that still do not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps

```
Solve[{ M == (n1 Cos[\[Theta]1] - n2 Cos[\[Theta]2])/(n1 Cos[\[Theta]1] + n2 Cos[\[Theta]2]) (n1 Cos[\[Theta]1] - n3 Cos[\[Theta]3])/(n1 Cos[\[Theta]1] + n3 Cos[\[Theta]3]), 
n1 Sin[\[Theta]1] == n2 Sin[\[Theta]2], 
n2 Sin[\[Theta]2] == n3 Sin[\[Theta]3] }
,{n1, n2, M}]

(*{{n1 -> n3 Csc[\[Theta]1] Sin[\[Theta]3], 
n2 -> n3 Csc[\[Theta]2] Sin[\[Theta]3], 
M -> ((Cos[\[Theta]2] Sin[\[Theta]1] -Cos[\[Theta]1] Sin[\[Theta]2]) (Cos[\[Theta]3] Sin[\[Theta]1] -Cos[\[Theta]1] Sin[\[Theta]3]))/((Cos[\[Theta]2] Sin[\[Theta]1] \+ Cos[\[Theta]1] Sin[\[Theta]2]) (Cos[\[Theta]3]Sin[\[Theta]1] +Cos[\[Theta]1] Sin[\[Theta]3]))}}*)
```

is what you're looking for?

Comment: I believe so (the programme keeps on crashing on my computer so I can't be certain) but why did you select all three $n_1, n_2, M$ as the variables? I only want $n_1$ on the left side. 
Is that so I could see the 3 different answers obtained?

Comment: There are three equations so you must specify three unknowns. You can designate one or more of the unknowns to be solved for and the rest to be eliminated. To get only `n1` and eliminate `{n2, M}`, use `Solve[eqns, n1, {n2, M}]`

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @user7077252 You'e welcome!